# How to get pip install PIL to work with pypy on windows 7

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pypy

This works outright on a linux VM I have sitting around but running "pip install pil" under pypy on windows 7 complains about things being defined multiple times:

~\Windows\v7.1\include\basetsd.h(76) : warning C4114: same type qualifier used more than once

Fixing these by editing the installed PIL source to #undef INT8/16/32 UINT8/16/32 on windows will resolve that issue but finally end up with:

LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'python27.lib'
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181

This "just works" with CPython on Windows7 and also just works with PyPy on Linux.

Does anyone know how to get it to work with pypy on windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

1) create a `libpypy-c.lib` from `PyPy\libpypy-c.dll` according to http://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2008/12/05/create-lib-file-from-dll/

2) change line 710 of `PyPy\lib-python\modified-2.7\distutils\command\build_ext.py` to `return ext.libraries + ['libpypy-c']`

3) Add the path to `libpypy-c.lib` to the LIB environment variable and rebuild PIL